# How many mappers and reducers run when we select * table_name where id = 10; in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How many mappers and reducers run when we select * table_name where id = 10; in hive ? Is it based on input splits or file size ? How to determine the no.of mappers and reducers in this case ?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every input split of the input table one mapper will be dispatched, where as the default size of the input split will the block size.

You could alter the number of mappers by modifying the `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` and `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` properties.

Speaking about the number of reducers in Hive, by default it is calculated using the `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` property where its default value is 1GB.

You will be able to configure the number of reducers by modifying the above property. Still you may also set the constant number of reducers for a job by using the `mapred.reduce.tasks` property.

Hope this helps.